# baking textures after texture painting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting, baking

I am trying to bake the textures from this model that I texture painted. When I try baking it the texture comes out black, I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

edit: This is my material that i made by following some tutorials on youtube, and this essentially allows me to paint the textures directly onto my mesh
[image]

[image]
when I export my model to unity there is no texture, so i tried baking it, and only a black texture came out, I need export the painted texture as a png so i can use it in unity
-Thanks

Comment: Please add screen captures to your post so we can see what is going on. Many possibilities and it would be better to narrow it down to a few of them.

Comment: Did you save the paited texture as an image on disk before baking?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i didn't realize, but you have to add another shader such as the diffuse bsdf shader before you can plug anything into the mix shader, if you dont, then the mix shader wont render

Comment: The UI actually hints at this by making the image output nodes yellow and the mix shader inputs green